# Positioning with absolute positions as percentages is putting things at a weird place

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make labels on my tick marks on a HTML5 range input.

My attempt looks like this ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og91v0ns/)):

```html
<div style="height: 20px; width: 100%;">
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 0%; text-align: center;">0.01</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 9.90991%; text-align: center;">1</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 19.9199%; text-align: center;">2</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 27.027%; text-align: center;">e</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 29.9299%; text-align: center;">3</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 39.9399%; text-align: center;">4</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 49.9499%; text-align: center;">5</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 59.96%; text-align: center;">6</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 69.97%; text-align: center;">7</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 79.98%; text-align: center;">8</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 89.99%; text-align: center;">9</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 100%; text-align: center;">10</span>
</div>
<input type="range" list="ticks" min="0" max="100" style="width: 100%;">
<datalist id="ticks">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>27</option>
  <option>29</option>
  <option>39</option>
  <option>49</option>
  <option>59</option>
  <option>69</option>
  <option>79</option>
  <option>89</option>
  <option>100</option>
</datalist>
</div>
```

I would expect that my `span`s would line up with the ticks on my range slider. However, they don't.

The misalignment seems to be in the labels, not the range input. When I inspect the elements in my Chrome inspector, the `span`s look like they're in the wrong place, even though their parent div looks like it has the right width.

Comment: looks okay here (Firefox/Mac)

Comment: Interesting! Yeah, it looks better on Chrome for me too. (Firefox doesn't display the ticks though, as usual)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several problems here:

1. If you position something absolute, the reference container is
   the next surrounding element that is set to `position: relative`. So
   to align your spans absolute in your div, this one needs to have an
   added `position: relative`
2. The absolute position sets the left border of your span. So your
   "10" will always pass the right border of your input. Though the
   left border of the 10 will be exacly on 100%.
3. As the span has no defined width, the `text-align: center` will
   not do anything (the center of what?)
4. Your input has a margin. Depending on the box-model you use it might
   either be part of the 100% or outside.

It works like this for me:

- Position the scale items exact and then a couple of pixels to the left (so the number itself is on the spot and not it's left border). Only the 10 needs to be positioned a little more to the left (99.5% here), since it has two digits.
- Put a container around your scale with padding to mirror the distance of your slider between the outer ends and the first tick.
- Make the container for your scale `relative` so this is where the scale items are positioned absolute to

I added some small javascript so one can see the value of the slider directly after it was moved - only for debugging purposes though.

The correct padding for the scale is somewhere between 6-8px to fit for all browsers.

```
<style>
#scaleContainer {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

#scale span {
  margin-left: -4px;
}
</style>
<head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="padding: 10px">
  <div id="sliderContainer" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="scaleContainer">
      <div id="scale" style="height: 20px; position: relative; width: 100%; margin: auto">
        <span style="position: absolute; left: -0.5%; text-align: center;">0.01</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 10%; text-align: center;">1</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 20%; text-align: center;">2</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 27%; text-align: center;">e</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 30%; text-align: center;">3</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 40%; text-align: center;">4</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 50%; text-align: center;">5</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 60%; text-align: center;">6</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 70%; text-align: center;">7</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 80%; text-align: center;">8</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 90%; text-align: center;">9</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 99.5%; text-align: center;">10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="slider" style="position: relative">
        <input type="range" list="ticks" min="0" max="100" style="width: 100%; margin: 0;" onchange="updateSliderValue(this.value);">
        <datalist id="ticks">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>20</option>
          <option>27</option>
          <option>30</option>
          <option>40</option>
          <option>50</option>
          <option>60</option>
          <option>70</option>
          <option>80</option>
          <option>90</option>
          <option>100</option>
        </datalist>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="showValue">
      <p>Slider value: <span id="sliderValue"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Why does it not match exactly, though? I would have thought that this would give you an exactly correct result.

Comment: I found it. Still it's slightly different for Firefox, but that's most likely just the way it is. I amend my answer. You can solve the problem by putting a container around the scale that has padding as much as the slider has a distance from the border to the first tick.